# Fixed width, height acording to parent div, and parent div heights acording to content and width rest of sreen?

Tags: html, css, height, width

Take this for an example:

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="leftDiv" style="background:green;"></div>
  <div id="rightDiv">
    <p>Sample content</p>
    <p>Sample content</p>
    <p>Sample content</p>
    <p>Sample content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want leftDiv to have a fixed width, lets say 100px, right div should then use the rest of the screen as width. I want leftDiv height's to be the same as rightDiv or at least 100% of screen height, and leftDiv's height to align with content.

I've found this code somewhere here on stackoverflow but the first problem with this is that it uses % as width for the div's, the second is that I want min-height to be 100% of screen:

```css
.floatLeft {
  float: left;
}
.child-left,
.child-right {
  width: 50%
}
.child-left {
  background: yellow;
}
.child-right {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 green;
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
.parent {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <!--[if IE]>
              <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
            <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child-left floatLeft">content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
      content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
      content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
      content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
      content content content content content content content content content content content content
    </div>

    <div class="child-right floatLeft">content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried playing around with it for many hours and can't figure it out. I can't set child-left to 100px width and child-right width auto, neither can I set a min-height to 100% even through I set *,html,body to 100% height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you're looking..

```css
#content {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  /* remove this line if not necessary */
}
#leftDiv,
#rightDiv {
  display: table-cell;
  min-height: 100%;
}
#leftDiv {
  width: 100px;
  background: green;
}
#rightDiv {
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="leftDiv"></div>
    <div id="rightDiv">
      <p>Sample content</p>
      <p>Sample content</p>
      <p>Sample content</p>
      <p>Sample content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When i put <!DOCTYPE html> before the <html> tag the min-height does not work, why?

Comment: If you're using <!DOCTYPE html> declaration,
Here is a trick.. Add the following to the css,

`html {
  height: 100%;
 }
 body {
  height: 100%;
  
  /* still if you need the margin */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 0;
 }`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you. But make sure your contents are properly wrapped because we are using overflow:hidden. Overflow:hidden clips the contents and doesnt even show a scroll bar for the rest of the contents.

```css
#outer {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
#left {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fdd;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
#right {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ddf;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>


</head>

<body>
  <div id="outer">
    <div id="left">
      Left Div
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      Right Div
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ok, didnt know that, then i have to find a solution without overflow:hidden, couse what i need is only IF content's height is smaler then screen then the height should be 100% but if content is heighter then screen, the height on left div should be same height as content and scroolbar should appear

Comment: overflow:auto; shows the scroll bar only when the content goes outside the screen. so in the left div change overflow to auto.

Comment: Yea that more like it :-) What if i want left div to follow down when i scroll down? Like if there is close to nothing content in left div and much content in right, when i scroll all the way down i shouldnt be able to see the top of left div.